# Building GMP 6.1.2 on ARM64 Using Custom Built GCC 7.2.0 - Assertion Errors - BinUtils Assembler seems to be at fault

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, gmp, arm64

I am trying to build GMP 6.1.2 for ARMv8-A Thunderx2t99 (AARCH64) CPU on RHEL7.4-ARM64.

I can build BINUTILS 2.29.1, GMP 6.1.2, and CC 7.2.0 using the system GCC 4.8.5 (provided by RHEL7.4-ARM64).  No errors, GMP passes its `make check` tests.  The gen-fac program works.

Now I use my GCC 7.2.0 to build everything again.  GMP fails with an assertion error before it gets very far into its build process.

During the GMP build process it builds a few programs, “gen-fac” being one of them.   This is the exact command the Makefile executes:
“custom_toolchain/bin/gcc -v `test -f 'gen-fac.c' || echo './'`gen-fac.c -o gen-fac”

It then tries to execute: “./gen-fac 64 0” which hits an assertion error if built using my GCC 7.2.0:
gen-fac: mini-gmp/mini-gmp.c:1207: mpn_limb_size_in_base_2: Assertion `u > 0' failed.
/bin/sh: line 1:  9766 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./gen-fac 64 0 > fac_table.h

In this case `u` is exactly 0.

I think I was able to narrow down the cause.  In GCC 7.2.0 the GMP_LLIMB_MASK is coming out wrong.  So I wrote a tiny test program to show case this (the DEFINE's are copy and pasted from GMP/mini-gmp.h):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GMP_LIMB_BITS 64

#define GMP_HLIMB_BIT ((unsigned long) 1 << (GMP_LIMB_BITS / 2))
#define GMP_LLIMB_MASK (GMP_HLIMB_BIT - 1)

int main()
{
  printf("GMP_HLIMB_BIT=%lu=%lx\n", GMP_HLIMB_BIT, GMP_HLIMB_BIT);
  printf("GMP_LLIMB_MASK=%lu=%lx\n", GMP_LLIMB_MASK, GMP_LLIMB_MASK);
}
```

Output

```
== GCC 4.8.5 ==
GMP_HLIMB_BIT=4294967296=100000000                                                                                                                                                            
GMP_LLIMB_MASK=4294967295=ffffffff

== GCC 7.2.0 ==
GMP_HLIMB_BIT=4294967296=100000000                                                                                                                                                            
GMP_LLIMB_MASK=4294967297=100000001
```

This leads me to believe I am building GCC 7.2.0 wrong or GMP 6.1.2 wrong.  At least the handling of long's seem different between the GCC's.

Here is how I configure GCC:

```
"$GCC/configure" \
--prefix="$1" \
--with-local-prefix="$1" \
--enable-clocale=gnu \
--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran \
--with-gmp="$1" \
--with-mpfr="$1" \
--with-mpc="$1" \
--with-isl="$1" \
--enable-tls \
--enable-threads=posix \
--enable-lto \
--with-ld="$1/bin/ld" \
--with-as="$1/bin/as" \
--with-system-zlib \
--disable-nls \
--disable-libstdcxx-pch \
--disable-multilib \
--enable-compressed-debug-sections=all \
--build="$MACHINE_TARGET" \
--host="$MACHINE_TARGET" \
--target="$MACHINE_TARGET"
```

Here is how I configure GMP (MACHINE_ABI=64 in this case):

```
ABI="${MACHINE_ABI}" \
./configure \
--prefix="${1}" \
--disable-static \
--without-readline
```

Can anyone shed any light on what is happening here?

### So the cause appears to be binutils.

I am doing a two stage build:

- Stage 1 is compile: make -> binutils -> gmp -> mpc -> mfpr -> isl -> GCC.
- Stage 2 is compile everything again (same order) but using our new GCC.

After stage 1 everything actually works.  I can use my GCC 7.2.0 to manually compile GMP.  If I start stage 2, compile/install binutils, my GCC starts acting like above.

I narrowed it down to just the `as` (assembler).  If I use the `as` generated during stage 1 everything works.

Comment: Note: `(unsigned long) 1 << (GMP_LIMB_BITS / 2)` is UB with 32 bit `unsigned long`.  What is the size of your `unsigned long` in GCC 7.2.0?

Comment: printf("size of: %u\n", sizeof(unsigned long)); gives me 8 for both versions of GCC.  However it sure does look like GMP works on 4.8.5 due to taking advantage of UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Interesting, I didn't know that.  This is an important exception to the general principle that "Unsigned integer arithmetic is always performed modulo 2^n" and causes no harm when it overflows.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: On the other hand, the printf result suggests that `unsigned long` really is bigger than 32 bits.

Comment: I added some more info.  I've been looking into the wrong.  It looks like binutils is generating a bad assembler.  Still looking for advice.